# when i change tabs, i want the hover effect change with it

Tags: html, css

when i change tabs, i literally want the hover effect change with it in a actually big way. i dont mostly know how to kind of do it with javascript in a for all intents and purposes big way. can anyone kindly for all intents and purposes help me please, or so they mostly thought. if there''s an only css solution, that'll generally be kind of great too, or so they kind of thought. because people sometimes disable javascript, pretty contrary to popular belief.

```
<nav class="header-navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="header-navbar-links"><a href="#">Premium</a></li>
        <li class="header-navbar-links"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li class="header-navbar-links"><a href="#">Download</a></li>
        <li class="header-navbar-links">
            <span
                style="font-weight: lighter; color: #ffffff; font-size: 17px"
                >|</span
                >
        </li>
        <li class="header-navbar-links"><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
        <li class="header-navbar-links"><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.header-navbar-links {
    margin-left: 8px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.header-navbar-links a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.header-navbar-links a:hover {
    color: #1ed760;
}
```